# PHP Regex extract date or date range

Tags: php, regex

I have a database full of movie titles and i want to extract the date which i've managed to do with the following:

```
(19|20)[0-9][0-9]
```

However i've noticed some of my dates are in ranges for example 1998-2003 or sometimes there is a space like 1998 - 2003. Is there any way to adapt the regex to match the ranges with or without a space?

Comment: I assume your question is not related to the database rather to the filter you apply on the result set, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\s*` to match zero or more spaces.

```
(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\s*-\s*(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/4)

If you want to match also the single year, then make the second part as optional.

```
(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}(?:\s*-\s*(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/5)

Comment: This does not match the single year anymore.